# Add count value to set

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I'm using django-taggit to tag items in a todo list app.

I'm trying to list each of the tags along with the number of actions associated with each tag so that it may read:

```
Tag A (1)
Tag B (3)
Tag C (2)
```

Tag A has 1 item, Tag B has 3, etc.

I added a boolean field to django-taggit.  So now I'm getting a list of tags like this:

```
visible_tags = Tag.objects.filter(visible=True).order_by('name')
hidden_tags = Tag.objects.filter(visible=False).order_by('name')
```

I can get the count of items (actions) like this:

```
for tag in visible_tags:
    print tag
    print Action.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[tag]).count()
```

Now I want to attach these counts to the visible_tags and hidden_tags set so that I can iterate over them in the template like this:

```
{% for tag in visible_tags %}
    {{ tag }} ({{ tag.count }})<br>
{% endfor %}
```

**How can I attach a .count value to each tag within visible_tags and within hidden_tags?**  I assume I have to iterate over all the tags in each set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use annotations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

```
from django.db.models import Count

Tag.objects.annotate(action_count=Count('action'))
```

(You might have to tweak that a bit. I'm guessing on the related name for `Action`)

Comment: that's what i thought but i don't think aggregation works with django-taggit? http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#aggregation

Comment: It might. The documented problem is with the opposite relation, i.e. if the OP wanted to count tags on `Action`: `Action.objects.annotate(Count('tags'))`.